# display dropdown value select options using React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to get the **startVisit** value from a dropdown select using useEffect in React Hooks.

But I don't want to show select **startVisit** value in **endVisit** dropdown.

How can i handle it?  how can i do?

Code:

```
  const [endVisitOptions, setEndVisitOptions] = useState(!startVisit);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("1",startVisit);  
    console.log("2",visits);  

    for(let x in startVisit)
    {
      console.log(startVisit[x]);      
    }

//your code logic here

    setEndVisitOptions(endVisitOptions);
  }, [startVisit]);





                <Dropdown
                    __key="visitId"
                    __value="title"
                    clearable={false}
                    label="Start Visit"
                    onChange={handleRecurringFormChange}
                    options={visits}
                    property="startVisit"
                    value={startVisit}
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="columns">
                <div className="column">
                  <Dropdown
                    __key="visitId"
                    __value="title"
                    clearable={false}
                    label="End Visit"
                    onChange={handleRecurringFormChange}
                    options={endVisitOptions}
                    property="endVisit"
                    value={endVisit}
                  />
```

Output data:

[image]

Dropdown UI data:
[image]

Comment: can you paste the full code on how you are passing the options to the end visit ? Is it maintained in state ?

Comment: yes code is mention @Shyam

Comment: are you making an api call to get the `endVisitOptions` ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKGq0H1N5VONHGzXglY0-M0BfdcHqtIH/view?usp=sharing you can check this file @Shyam

Comment: `endVisitOptions ` is usestate where i save `endVisit` value which display only endVisit.. @Shyam

Comment: i am confused here . how you are getting the drop down values to the select . I mean the list of options for the select . Also what is the initial start and end visit options . Its difficult to help without seeing the full code .

Comment: can you do it dummy data value `startVisit` and `endVisit` as shown output data. @Shyam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may want to filter the visits to not contain the startVisit before calling setEndVisitOptions.

```
if (startVisit) {     
  const filteredData = visits.filter(v => v.visitId !== startVisit.visitId);
  setEndVisitOptions(filteredData)
}
```

Comment: It is possible just only show the `forward` value of `startVisit` in dropdown @Abhay have you get my point? I don't want to display the old value like `a` `b` `c` if select `b` just show the `b` `c` in dropdown.

Comment: It would be possible to show only the 'forward' value. If the array is sorted then you can find the index of currently selected value with indexOf or findIndex and slice the array from that index, refer array.prototype.slice in MDN.
BTW, could you please consider accepting the answer if it's fine? Thanks.

Comment: yes can i you add the `'forward'` value. code.. it will be highly appreciated @Abhay

Comment: First you can get the index -
const currValIndex = visits.findIndex(v => v.visitId !== startVisit.visitId);
and then slice the array with that index
const forwardValues = visits.slice(currValIndex);
then set that as end visits
setEndVisitOptions(forwardValues);